# How to have a many to one relationship EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, entity-framework-core

**Context:**

*I have a relationship*

```
class Service {
   public virtual int Sequencial { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ServiceType Type { get; set; }
   ...
}

class ServiceType {
   public virtual int Sequencial { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*In NHibernate class would look like this*

> Id(s => s.Sequencial,
>   "SERVICE_ID").GeneratedBy.Sequence("SQ_SERVICE_ID");
>   References(s => s.ServiceType, "SERVICE_TYPE_ID"); 
> Map(a => a.Nome, "SERVICE_NAME");
>   ...

how I can implement *References(s => s.ServiceType, "SERVICE_TYPE_ID")*, in other words, how I can implement many-to-one in EF?

Comment: Just add a property `public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }` to the class `ServiceType`.

Comment: The desired relationship is already defined by convention because of the `Service.Type` reference navigation property. What else do you need?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes ServiceType is a "utility class". I have a list of types and I need to get the type of service, not the other way around. Do you understand?

Comment: On the one-side of a relation (`ServiceType`), you can declare a collection, on the many-side (`Service`) a simple navigation property. However, according to @IvanStoev, your desired relation is already defined by convention in your existing code.

Comment: The relationship is already defined, but how do I map it in DBcontext class?
About collection, I can't bidirectional mapping. Conceptually, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Service {
   public virtual int Sequencial { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ServiceType Type { get; set; }
 }

class ServiceType {
  public virtual int Sequencial { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public IList<Service> Services{get;set;}
 }
```

Use these two links for more guidance

asp

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

asp core

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx

Comment: Can you applying in my case? 
It´s good to be registered here without depending on the stability of the links. :)